# How to remove android sdk in android studio？

Tags: android, sdk

How to remove android sdk in android studio just like how Eclipse can do?

i want change a special sdk for my project, i tried replace android sdk in Android Studio, but this cannot be done.

**Screenshot of How Eclipse remove Android SDK**

[image]

**My Question is:**

How to perform this in Android Studio as well?

Comment: yes。 that eclipse，  not studio 。 I want to do the same thing in studio，But there is no way.

Answer (score -1):

1. Click on the Project Structure icon , or File > Project Structure

[image]

2. Select SDK
3. Select the SDK platform that you want to modify
4. Remove the existing android.jar and add your own.
5. Apply and done!

[image]

Comment: 李彦祖 is asking for eclipse not for android studio

Comment: ...really?   Is that what I mean?

Comment: thanks。 
You said this is to change the sdk version or path that comes with android, but my sdk is just a classes.jar,
Maybe I didn't express it clearly, sorry,
I mean, I want to change my own sdk without android's own sdk, because android does not have the module I need, but in eclipse can be successfully compiled by removing android sdk. But android studio does not have this operation,
What I want to know is how does android studio perform such an operation?

Comment: I see, thanks for the clarification. You wanted to add the Android SDK jar to the project? I'll update the answer. I wonder why I got downvoted.